# How Highstock determines date

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to create some chart using Highstock.I want to know how Highstock determines dates?

in [this](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line) example `JSON` look like this:

```
[1366934400000,417.20],
[1367193600000,430.12],
[1367280000000,442.78],
/* May 2013 */
[1367366400000,439.29],
[1367452800000,445.52],
[1367539200000,449.98],
[1367798400000,460.71],
[1367884800000,458.66],
[1367971200000,463.84],
[1368057600000,456.77],
[1368144000000,452.97]
```

How Highstock determines that `460.71` related to `Monday May6 2013`?

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first number in the x/y pair is the javascript date. It is in milliseconds since the POSIX time 0 (00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970).

In the data ([1367798400000,460.71]) the `1367798400000` is the number of milliseconds since POSIX 0.